# Alternative to if statement method that works for larger list

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, unity-game-engine

```
if(teamData[0].currentGoals > teamData[1].currentGoals)
    {
        teamData[0].teamWins += 1;
        teamData[1].teamLosses += 1;
    }

else if (teamData[0].currentGoals < teamData[1].currentGoals)
    {
        teamData[1].teamWins += 1;
        teamData[0].teamLosses += 1;
    }

else if (teamData[0].currentGoals == teamData[1].currentGoals)
    {
        teamData[0].teamDraws += 1;
        teamData[1].teamDraws += 1;
    }
```

Code basically does what its needed to do but it just won't work for the project I'm working on. 
Please help any resources to read and advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Sorry I'm not that great at explaining things. I want to be able to compare about 30 more items just like this (if statement). I need a win,lose and draw as results. 
It's a football tournament.

Comment: What's the question? How do you want "larger arrays" to be handled?

Comment: _"it just won't work for the project I'm working on"_ -- meaning what, exactly? How is it that the code _"does what its [sic] needed to do"_, but at the same time _"just won't work"_? By what measure would different code be better?

Comment: I just thought it'd be too long.

Comment: Use `@UserName` when replying to a specific comment, so that the author of that comment can be notified. As for _"too long"_, in what way? Please show the "too long" code, so we can understand what it is you think you need to do, absent a better solution.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm not too knowledgeable on this but isn't repeating that same if else statements about 30 times pretty bad? 
Mostly from what I've read... repeating your code means your doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, repeating (copy/paste) your code is generally a bad idea. But there's nothing in your question that explains why and how the code you posted would wind up being repeated. The logic you are showing would be typical of handling the result of a match between two teams, but in that case presumably you'd have some collection of those matches (games). There's nothing in your question that would allow anyone to _know_ what problem you're trying to solve (not that there won't be people so eager for the "win" that they'll try anyway...but you'll get the _best_ help faster with a good question).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for that. It seems that what you said is what I lack: Collection of the matches. 

You made it clear to me what I actually need to work on is the 'code' leading up to the one I posted. If you have any resources that may help me in my problem I'd appreciate it. Seems I got focused on the wrong thing.

Thank you once again.

Comment: @THANLSTnx If you can edit the question to better reflect what the earlier code is that you need help with, then we who are eager for a "win" are happy to help :)  If, on the other hand, it turns out to be another question altogether then perhaps finalize this question and open a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming "larger arrays" mean more games, and that games always have two teams:

```
// Game class has teamData list/array:
List<Game> games = new List<Game>();

// ... Populate games

foreach (var game in games) {
  var g0 = game.teamData[0].currentGoals, g1 = game.teamData[1].currentGoals;

  if (g0 > g1) {
    game.teamData[0].teamWins++;;
    game.teamData[1].teamLosses++;
  }
  else if (g1 > g0) {
    game.teamData[1].teamWins++;;
    game.teamData[0].teamLosses++;
  }
  else {
    game.teamData[0].teamDraws++;
    game.teamData[1].teamDraws++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this one just expand the same way?

Comment: @pcdev's answer is probably based on the fact that in your question you have some part of the code that doesn't show the whole picture, so people will show you the easiest solution to handling more than the one result presented in your code. If you update the code piece in the question people can give better answers.

Comment: "I want to be able to compare about 30 more items" @THANLSTnx  @MarkusDeibel Yes, I stated my assumption: that "more items" means "more games".  If, on the other hand you mean you have more properties (than just `currentGoals`) to compare between the two teams, or more teams per game, then this requires another solution altogether.  I'm happy to expand my answer if you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
var t1 = teamData[0];
var t2 = teamData[1];

t1.teamWins = t1.currentGoals > t2.currentGoals ? t1.teamWins + 1 : t1.teamWins;
t1.teamLosses = t1.currentGoals < t2.currentGoals ? t1.teamLosses + 1 : t1.teamLosses;
t1.teamDraws = t1.currentGoals == t2.currentGoals ? t1.teamDraws + 1 : t1.teamDraws;

t2.teamWins = t2.currentGoals > t1.currentGoals ? t2.teamWins + 1 : t2.teamWins;
t2.teamLosses = t2.currentGoals < t1.currentGoals ? t2.teamLosses + 1 : t2.teamLosses;
t2.teamDraws = t2.currentGoals == t1.currentGoals ? t2.teamDraws + 1 : t2.teamDraws;
```

or:

```
...
if (t1.currentGoals > t2.currentGoals) {t1.teamWins++; t2.teamLosses++;}
else if (t1.currentGoals < t2.currentGoals) {t1.teamLosses++; t2.teamWins++;}
else {t1.teamDraws++; t2.teamDraws++;}
```

for multiple games just insert one of mentioned method to method with refs:

```
private void processResult(ref [yourTeamDataType] t1, ref [yourTeamDataType] t2) { ... comparison code ... }
```

and just compare like:

```
foreach (var game in games)
    processResult(ref game.teamData[0], ref game.teamData[1]);
```

Comment: No problem :) I updated based on your edit... still wrong question ?